# Passing string variables through include in twig and slim framework

Tags: twig, slim

I am using Slim Framework and Twig.

I want to apply the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using partials. I have a form that is reused in several views with different variables such as titles and route (url) names.

I am struggling on how to make it work on url names.

For example, there is this link using the ´urlFor´ helper with parameter as follows inside a view:

```
<a href="{{urlFor('route.name', {parameter: value})}}">The link</a>
```

So that is the link I want to pass to the partial template since, it is different in each view, I want to use the partial form. I have tried several approaches but it does not work. I don't know how to pass this string containing `'` inside.

For example, I have tried this partial call inside the parent view like this:

```
{% include 'partials/partial.php' with {'theUrl': "urlFor('route.name', {parameter: value})"} %}
```

And inside the partial like this:

```
<a href="{{theUrl}}">Show more</a>
```

It does not work because in the browser's url I see the following:

```
http://myproject.dev/pages/urlFor('route.name',%20%7Bparameter:%201%7D)
```

It looks like it is not being escaped properly. Any ideas how to fix this when passing route names with `urlFor()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the greatest possibility for testing i think i found the problem. You are simply adding the function inside a string and that does not give the parser an oportunity to resolve the method, because it's basicly just a string.

```
{% include 'partials/partial.php' with {'theUrl': "urlFor('route.name',{parameter: value})"} %}
```

Should be

```
{% include 'partials/partial.php' with {'theUrl': urlFor('route.name',{parameter: value})} %}
```

Comment: You may consider as a better practice to use [`{{ include() }}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) function instead of the `{% include %}` tag, because `{% ... %}` is used to control your template's structure, where `{{ ... }}` is used to render stuff. Your answer is good though.

Comment: Not that are doubting you, but more out of curiosity. Are most includes naturally related to structures instead of rendering. In other words isn't an anti pattern to render web content with includes, instead of parsing data and doing it with repeats and so on?